# Can I upgrade my cPanel or File Manager on Shared Hosting?

Tags: cpanel, file-manager, wysiwyg

I'm using hostgator shared hosting which uses cPanel. The version of cPanel is very old and so is both the file manager and wysiwyg editor. I would like to upgrade them.

How can I upgrade them to new versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple... ***you*** can't... talk to hostgator since you don't have root and its them your paying.

Comment: if i can't, then how i can edit a file using cms?
that means its possible...

Comment: You have many ways but that's another question entirely. If you hate using the file manager then make changes to your files using FTP or SFTP with a FTP client such as FlashFXP, CuteFTP or FileZilla. Then use your own editor locally, such as Sublime, Brackets, Dreamweaver, Notepad and so on.

Comment: You first point of call should be hostgator, they may upgrade the server or migrate you to a newer server... its a common procedure for hosting companies to migrate users on request.

Comment: my web host is a hostgator reseller

Comment: They will have multiple servers... talk to them.